# Short Circuit in my Garage light socket

Tags: motion-sensor

A few months back I installed a Lutron motion sensor switch in my garage.  I noticed later that one of my exterior outlets that is in the garage circuit stopped working.  So I plugged a Sperry GFCI tester into the outlet and completely disconnected the Lutron in the garage and pigtailed the blacks together and the whites in such a way so that the Sperry plugged into the exterior outlet showed 'normal'.  However I just could not figure out how to connect the Lutron back.  At this point I noticed that the garage light that is controlled by the Lutron switch was showing a short.  When I use a Multimeter and touch the two terminals on the bulb holder they show a short.  I thought maybe I got the wiring wrong again, so I removed all the connections I had made in the switch receptacle (where the Lutron was to have gone)and then checked for the short at the bulb again and I was surprised to see that the short still was present.  Any idea why this is happening?

Some other information - I notice that the breaker for the garage in the breaker panel is wobbly.  There is also a GFCI outlet in the garage circuit and I have tried resetting that but it makes no difference.  Some questions I have are:

1. Could a problem anywhere in the house cause this short?  Or should I look only in the garage circuit?
2. There are 3 blacks and 3 white wires along with a bare copper in the switch outlet controlling the garage light where I had initially installed the Lutron.  How should the pigtails be in this outlet?  If I tie all my blacks together then I get power on two of the 3 whites.  I know which black goes to the garage light (used a tone generator to find this with the breaker off) but I am flummoxed at this point regarding the short.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are there any other lights on the same circuit? A turned-incandescent light has a low enough resistance to look like a short

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the switch box in question please?

Comment: Ask a separate question about the wobbly breaker. There are often reasons for that.  If able, post a pic of the breaker panel. No need to remove the deadfront, Also try to post a pic of the labeling.

Comment: Lights as foxy lover suggest or simple transformers can look like a short to dc but are fine with ac a true short would trip the breaker.